# Why doesn't entropy get decreased in adiabatic expansion process?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic, disorder

I was reading the second step of Carnot cycle in which the system undergoes adiabatic expansion doing work & thus decreasing the internal energy of itself. The entropy didn't change as no further heat energy was supplied or taken out; it remained the same as it was after the first step of the cycle that is $\Delta S = \frac{Q_\text{isothermal}}{T}.$

However, I wonder why wouldn't the disorder of the system decrease after the adiabatic expansion; the system is doing work & is losing its internal energy with fall in temperature . Wouldn't this decrease the randomness or disorder of the system after-all it is now less energetic? And doesn't less energetic mean lesser number of microstates & lesser disorder  in the system? So, why should the entropy which is the measure of the disorder changes?

Could anyone please help me shun my confusion?

Comment: It is true that T decreases, but the volume V increases. The increase in disorder due to the increase in V exactly compensates the decrease due to the change in internal energy

Comment: The very simple answer to this question is that entropy is not a measure of disorder in the usual sense. Trying to understand entropy as disorder might be the source of confusion here. Of course, if by "disorder" you actually mean "number of microstates" (which is not the meaning of the word disorder), then bruce smitherson's argument is entirely correct.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I am just curious, what definition of disorder is the universally accepted one?

Comment: @brucesmitherson Well, according to [the dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disorder) it could refer to confusion, leprosy, or rioting in the streets, but the entry about phase-space volume seems to be missing... ;) Actually, following Humpty-Dumpty, I believe that one should use any word for whatever meaning one likes if it enables communication. And the heuristic use of disorder in physics to refer to entropy is commonplace and perfectly acceptable. But it's worth occasionally reminding beginners that entropy is *not* necessarily disorder in any intuitive sense.

Comment: @brucesmitherson Also, that comment could be an answer :)

Comment: @MarkMitchison Just like we "occasionally" remind beginners that work is not necessarily the usual intuitive understanding of the word. I disagree on your statement that "entropy is not a measure of disorder in the usual sense" - just because the everyday use of a word is imprecise or the word has multiple meanings, doesn't change the fact that entropy is a measure of disorder in a system.

Comment: @Steeven OK. But perhaps then I am at fault for being imprecise. I meant simply that disorder (i.e. entropy) in physics has a different meaning from the one in the dictionary, and also from the one in everyday language: on that I believe we can agree. It seemed to me that the OP would benefit from this reminder. Regarding your statement, I would contest that entropy is actually a measure of the observer's ignorance, which a priori has nothing to do with the intrinsic disorder of the system in any reasonable sense whatsoever. Unless of course you simply *define* disorder to mean entropy.

Comment: Q isothermal is not the same as Q reversible.  And the natural order is for entropy to increase - not decrease.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: [Entropy is not disorder](http://entropysite.oxy.edu/entropy_isnot_disorder.html). I'm not using the word `disorder` like that attributed to _messy_ desks or _shuffled_ cards etc.; what I mean is simply the number of microstates; that's it.